# How to change dropdown text in bootstrap-vue.js dynamically

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I am using this code for dropdown:

```
<b-dropdown size="sm" text="Update" split class="m-2">
                    <b-dropdown-item-button>Action</b-dropdown-item-button>
                    <b-dropdown-item-button>Another action</b-dropdown-item-button>
                    <b-dropdown-item-button>Something else here...</b-dropdown-item-button>
                  </b-dropdown>
```

How do I update the "**text**" item dynamically?

Comment: `{{ myText }}`?

Comment: @depperm No, it doesn't work, I have already tried.

Comment: `it doesn't work` how? was there an error? did it not update like you thought? is `myText` a prop or computed prop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if i put a colon infront of `text="text"`

```
<b-dropdown size="sm" :text="text" split class="m-2">
```